# Advanced model validation in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy

I have following following model:

```
class Foo(DeclarativeBase):
    code = Column(u'code', String(length=255))
    ctype = Column(u'ctype', String(length=255))
```

I need to validate one field, with respect to another one.

For example

`if ctype == "bar" and code == "buzz": raise ValueError`

Do not create object and record in db on commit. And if no exception was raised create all as usual.

I've tried to use. [Simple validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators)
and  tried to setup 'before_insert' event using [before_insert mapper event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#mapper-events)
and wrote such code:

```
def validate_foo(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.ctype == "bar" and target.code == "buzz":
        raise ValueError

event.listen(Foo, 'before_insert', validate_foo)
```

When ctype == "bar" and code == "buzz", it does not create any object in DB. It does not raise any exception. But it creates Foo object instance(without db).

What is the best way to do such validation?

Comment: How do you define "best"? Some might want to put this validation directly in the database. others might want to put it in the model itself without any tie-in to SQLAlchemy. Others might want to use SQLAlchemy events you've shown above. There is no "right answer" to that question. Is your actual question why your `validate_foo` method is not being called? If so, you should provide more detail (such as example code that you can run where you expect to cause your validation event to fire, but it is not firing)

Comment: `validate_foo` actually was called, but it looks like it called in separate thread or so. And my code didn't receive that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with creating trigger in DB(I use postgresql). And catching integrity error in python code.